# How Can I Normalize a Table if Some Attributes Have No Established Dependancies?

Tags: database, normalization, functional-dependencies

I will put this out there first, this is a homework question.  I do not expect someone to answer it for me, at least not specifically.  I am not sure how to normalize if some of the attributes are not functionally dependent on another attribute.  How do you determine a key?  Here is an example of what I am talking about:

Given the follow table:
T( Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet)
**The Colors are the table attributes**

Suppose we have the following dependencies:
Red + Orange---> Yellow; Red--> Green,Blue; Green---->Blue

How do I include Indigo and Violet in 2nd NF and 3rd NF when they have no established dependancies? I understand how to do put the tables into 1st, 2nd, and 3rd NF, but I just don't know what to do when there is no established dependancies.

I have looked everywhere but can not find the answer.  Can anyone give me a little guidance or point me in the direction of where I can learn how to solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: *"How do you determine a key?"* What does your textbook say? Every database textbook I've ever seen has at least one algorithm for determining every candidate key based on the FDs. Speaking informally, every attribute that appears in *none* of the FDs must be part of *every* candidate key.

Comment: That makes perfect sense...the attributes must be part of the key, they just do not go anywhere by themselves. Thank you